# Task "default" not found. use --force to continue grunt error

Tags: gruntjs

I am Followed all the instructions mentioned over **[HERE](http://gruntjs.com/getting-started)** to setup `npm` , `grunt-cli` and grunt in my project , now i make a `Gruntfile.js` and have the following code in it:

```
module.export = function(grunt) {
    grunt.registerTask('default' , ' ' , function(){
        grunt.log.write('This grunt task is pointless !');
    });     
};
```

the gruntfile is in my root directory of the project , when i navigate to the project from the CLI , and run the below command:

```
grunt
```

I get an error:

> Task "default" not found. use --force to continue.

Now why am i getting this error and what am i missing ?

Thank you.

Alex-z.

Answer (score 4):

Typo: first line should be `module.exports` (note final `s`)